# Is Sydney good for scuba diving?

Tags: australia, diving, sydney

I'm heading over to Sydney soon and would like to get some dives in locally while staying in the city. I'm interested in diving specifically near or not to far from central sydney, either shore or boat dives. I'm hoping for an abundance of marine life, good visibility and the potential to see more than just fish - I've heard shark encounters are possible in the area.

Comment: Asking for the favourite three is polling, and against the rules of the [faq].  I'd recommend rephrasing to a more objective question as in its current form it risks more downvotes :/

Comment: Hey Marcus, thanks for the update, but polling isn't just asking for their 3 favourite, polling is asking opinion or for people's thoughts.  :/  Polling is best suited for a forum, rather than a Q&A site.